# Is it possible to compress a very large file (~30 GB) using gzip?

Tags: filesystems, files, compression, gzip

Is it possible to compress a very large file (~30 GB) using gzip?  If so, what commands, switches, and options should I use?

Or is there another program (preferably one commonly available on Ubuntu distributions) that I can use to compress/zip very large files?  Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Most hardcore compressor is xz, or its parallel version, pxz. `pxz -9ve - <in >out.xz` and you will bake a chicken on your PC, but the result will be around 60% of the gzip result. You need around 7 GB for that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK there is no limit of size for `gzip` - at least not 30GB. Of course, you need the space for the zipped file on your disc, both versions will be there simultanously while compressing.

`bzip2` compresses files (not only big ones :-) better, but it is (sometimes a lot) slower.

Comment: bzip2 is especially good at compressing source code (and the like). It is a good competitor to gzip for generic use too. Availability for gzip across different operating systems is better than bzip2

Comment: Is bzip2 lossless compression?  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, gzip/bzip2/etc... are all lossless.

Comment: And there is `pbzip`, too - that will use more than one CPU-core. But still way slower than `gzip`.

Comment: @Nils: on my Ubuntu there is only `pbzip2`

Comment: If you want a higher-compression alternative to `gzip`, use `xz`.  It's better, faster (and *much* faster to decompress), and generally recommended.  If you want a lower-compression faster alternative to gzip, there's `lzop` / `lz4`.  (`xz -0` is actually a good choice for medium speed.)

Comment: Also, cuneiform's answer is somewhat correct.  `gzip`'s file header only has 32bits to store the file size.  So `.gz` files of longer input will have the wrong size listed in the metadata, but the compressed datastream will be fine.  `gzip` will decompress the whole thing, just give wrong results for `--list`.

Answer (score 9):

if you need a good compresion rate, you can try lzma. it is faster and more efficient than bzip2 and may be faster even than gzip (i don't know that for sure)

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/lzma-better-compression-than-bzip2-on-unix-linux/

Comment: `lzma` is deprecated in favour of `xz` now.  Same algorithm, somewhat different (improved?) file format wrapped around it.  LZMA is slower than gzip, but at max speed it's still fairly good compression on highly redundant stuff like JSON data.  (`xz -0`)

Answer (score 5):

If you are running into the limit, rearrange. Instead of:

```
gzip file
```

do:

```
gzip < file > file.gz
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

> The gzip format represents the input size modulo 2^32, so the `--list` option reports incorrect uncompressed sizes and compression ratios for uncompressed files 4 GB and larger.

So, take `bzip2` (v1.0.2 and upwards) or `xz`.

Comment: If it should precisely be gzip only, then your file has to be divided into smaller parts up to 4 Gb each.

Comment: There are file splitters available for this.

Comment: Well, it doesn't *have* to be split up, it's just that the reported sizes will be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

XZ set to lowest compression may well [beat](http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html) gzip for speed and compression.