# How portable is a gzip file over 4 GB in size?

Tags: files, tar, gzip, portability

To backup a snapshot of my work, I run a command like `tar -czf work.tgz work` to create a gzipped tar file, which I can then drop in cloud storage. However, I have just noticed that gzip has a 4 GB size limit, and my `work.tgz` file is more than 4 GB.

Despite that, if I create a gzip tar file on my current computer (running Mac OS X 10.15.4, gzip version is called Apple gzip 287.100.2) I can successfully retrieve it. So gunzip works on a >4GB in my particular case. But I want to be able to create and read these large gzip files on either Mac OS X or Linux, and possibly other systems in the future.

My question is: will I be able to untar/gunzip large files anywhere? In other words, how portable is a gzip file which is more than 4 GB in size? Does it matter if I create it on Mac OS, Linux, or something else?

A bit of online reading suggests gzip will successfully gzip/gunzip a larger file, but will not correctly record the uncompressed size, because the size is stored as a 32 bit integer. Is that all the limit is?

Comment: If the compressed file was created with no issues, then any system with the tools to decompress it will have no issues doing so.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to compress a very large file (~30 GB) using gzip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39934/is-it-possible-to-compress-a-very-large-file-30-gb-using-gzip)

Comment: Just for the record (since it’s not your use case), apart from ``gzip`` potential limitations (I don’t know about them), remember that some file systems have a maximum file size limit too. I’m thinking of FAT32, for instance, which has a 4 GiB file size limit.

Comment: @NasirRiley That's a dangerous assumption, when extensions to various file formats exist. (Speaking generally)

Comment: Files this big are silly anyway. Why can't you split it into smaller archives? Think back to the floppy disk days!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings There's nothing dangerous about it. If it was created with no issues, then any tool will be able to open it unless something rather bizarre was done. There's no way that anyone can account for all of that but if there's a .tgz file, it's safe to say that tar will be able to decompress it or that unzip or other software such was Winzip will be able to decompress it.

Comment: @NasirRiley I said "speaking generally". If you make a backup, that doesn't mean you can do a restore. In this case I'd tend to agree that a gzip is probably a gzip, but if you're relying on "I was able to compress this file on system A" to also mean "I will be able to decompress it on system B" without further verification or information, you're just asking for trouble. That is not the proper way to make decisions. In other words, asking this question is entirely reasonable and diligent.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings What trouble, exactly? That you wouldn't be able to decompress the file? Alert the media! In this case, the OP knows what type of file it is because he compressed it. There's the possibility that it may not be the type of file that the extension indicates but that's a different can of worms. My comment is obviously concerning a file that is known to be the type of file that was created by the compression utility and not to cover everything else that could possibly happen. Otherwise, any advice would be useless as it could never do it.

Comment: You're missing so many possible varying factors that I don't even know where to begin, @Nasir. Not to worry.

Comment: @breversa : Solaris 2.6 (aka Solaris 6) had a 2GiiB limit ... so SIMS (Sun Internet Mail System) would stop backups at 2 GiiB, even if they weren't finished, without telling you.  Even if you were on Solaris 7 and didn't have that limit.  It was a bad day when our mail system crashed, and we found out that we didn't actually have any full backups, only an incomplete one + incrementals for the last month.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If you're that concerned, then feel free to list them out. You can then proceed to do the same for nearly every comment and answer across the Stack Exchange network. There are always many possibly varying factors with there being so many that they can't possibly all be accounted for. If you want to go on and on about everything that could possibly ever occur, then be my guest. It's your time, not mine.

Comment: @Nasir No, it is wildly off-topic. But you can ask a new question on SE if you like. The only one going "on and on about" it is you  As I said, "not to worry", i.e. conversation over. Cheers.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Who cares? If it's off-topic, then why did you bring it up?

Comment: @NasirRiley You did...... _conversation over_!!!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I have just noticed that gzip has a 4 GB size limit

More accurately, the `gzip` format can’t correctly store uncompressed file *sizes* over 4GiB; it stores the lower 32 bits of the uncompressed size, and `gzip -l` misleadingly presents that as the size of the original data. The result is that, up to `gzip` 1.11 included, `gzip -l` won’t show the right size for any compressed file whose original size is over 4GiB.

Apart from that, there is no limit due to `gzip` itself, and `gzip`ped files over 4GiB are portable. The format is specified by [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) and support for it is widely available.

The confusion over the information presented by `gzip -l` [has been fixed in `gzip` 1.12](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=10157); [`gzip -l`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gzip.git/commit/?id=32fef43b442c7abc70414863d64718cd06f6477a) now decompresses the data to determine the real size of the original data, instead of showing the stored size.

> Will I be able to untar/gunzip large files anywhere?

Anywhere that can handle large files, and where spec-compliant implementations of `tar` and `gunzip` are available.

> In other words, how portable is a gzip file which is more than 4 GB in size?

The `gzip` format itself is portable, and `gzip` files are also portable, regardless of the size of the data they contain.

> Does it matter if I create it on Mac OS, Linux, or something else?

No, a `gzip` file created on any platform can be uncompressed on any other platform with the required capabilities (in particular, the ability to store large files, in the context of this question).

See also [Compression Utility Max Files Size Limit | Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469298/86440).

Comment: The rfc1952 you link to is very clear that ISIZE (the last 4 bytes of the file) "contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input
            data **modulo 2^32.**". (emphasis mine). So I don't see how it cannot "correctly" store that. Besides, I guess that the point of the question was rather to collect info about broken system who would choke on gzip files > 4G.

Comment: It correctly stores something which isn’t the original file size.

Comment: Does it actually store something when used in a pipeline?

Comment: @SimonRichter good question, and it does: `echo "This is a pipe test" | gzip -9 | cat > file.gz` (extra `cat` to ensure `gzip` is writing to a pipe) produces a `file.gz` which shows accurate info with `gzip -l`. `gzip -l` doesn’t show sizes when given its input from a pipe however; compare `gzip -l file.gz`, `gzip -l < file.gz` and `cat file.gz | gzip -l`.

Comment: It can (could) store/know the size if the compressed output is only a single block. Once it had to stream the first compressed block out, it can no longer modify the header.

Comment: @eckes, that linked RFC seems to indicate that the size field is in the tail part of the file, and repeating Stephen's command with some bigger input still gives me the right size from `gzip -l`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, also, `gzip -l` seeks back from the end of the file to get to the size from there, and it can't do that from a pipe.

Comment: @SimonRichter yes, because it does **not (even pretend to) store the file size**, as this answer wrongly suggests. FWIW, multiple gzip files concatenated work exactly the same as a single gzip file, and doing it all at once would **not** compress it better, as soon as the input data is larger than 64k or 128k. So tar or gzip could compress the output by chunks instead of in one single go, which would also have the advantage that the output would be *almost* seekable.

Comment: @UncleBilly, I believe the `--rsyncable` option does something like that.

Comment: @UncleBilly the problem is that `gzip` itself suggests that the value it stores is the file size; for example, here’s what `gzip -l` shows for a 17,157,184,425-byte file compressed down to 8,561,894,221 bytes: `compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name` `8561894221          4272282537 -100.4% filename`. It shows the real compressed file size, and no indication that the uncompressed file size is modulo 2³², and calculates the ratio based on those values... The docs mention the caveat, but `gzip -l` itself is still misleading.

Comment: For seekable `gz` files, see [`gztool`](https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool).

Comment: @UncleBilly, what do you mean "doesn't even pretend to"? That 32-bit value is exactly the file size in what's likely to be a huge majority of the cases, and even when the actual size is higher and the value overflows, _pretend_ sounds like a very apt description for the result.

Comment: @ilkkachu Why don't you guys go read the RFC? As I already mentioned in my first comment, that ISIZE field is NOT supposed to be the size of the "original file". That's really not hard to grasp. As to the `-l` option of gzip, it should be deprecated and no longer documented: there are at least 3 cases where it doesn't print anything sensible for perfectly valid gzip data 1. data larger than 4G 2. data made up of multiple members. 3. data read from a non-seekable file. People should ignore the `-l` and `-N` options of gzip and treat them as historical artifacts.

Comment: As to why they didn't deprecate `-l`, I have no idea but maybe some nobody like me has suggested it once, and now the idea is *poisoned*, and doing it would feel like a capitulation ;-) [Just kidding, open source devs are not as bad as stackexchange answerers LMAO]

Comment: @UncleBilly I had read the RFC, and yes, the `ISIZE` field is documented as storing the file size modulo 2³², but that doesn’t change the fact that `gzip -l` is documented as showing the uncompressed file size, which is where all the confusion comes from (which I think is also what you’re saying). I don’t understand where you get that my answer is suggesting that `gzip` is supposed to store the size correctly. It’s perhaps worth noting that the RFC is post-facto documentation; `gzip` wasn’t implemented based on the RFC.

Comment: @StephenKitt it's documented as the size of the original *data*, not of the original *file*. As to your [originalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Originalism) argument (what was gzip first), it does hold a lot of sway in the court of public opinion, I cannot argue with that.

Comment: @UncleBilly `gzip -l` is documented as showing the uncompressed file size; go and check for yourself, I’ll wait. And then perhaps, instead of deflecting, you can answer my question: where do you get that my answer (not the comments) is suggesting that `gzip` is supposed to store the size correctly?

Comment: "the gzip format can’t correctly store uncompressed file sizes over 4GiB". But, as I said, you're also not answering the question at all. Notice that the OP isn't even using the `gzip` utility; they're using `tar -czf`, which is using zlib directly. And the vagueness of your answer also creates confusion (many people mix up gzip with zip, which unlike gzip, **does** have a 4G limit -- the zip64 format is not compatible and not supported everywhere); some non-technical person reading it will get the impression that it's still something not exactly kosher with gzipping data larger than 4G.

Comment: @ilkkachu "pulling us all down to wrestle in the mud now are we" Oh, that's nice, really. **plonk**

Comment: @UncleBilly, right, because implying that the people you're talking to wouldn't want to "capitulate"  because of _who_ said something instead of _what_ was said is so much nicer.

Comment: @UncleBilly, I did read the RFC (I even referred to it above) and I still expect that storing the size mod 2^32 just so happens to store the actual size in a whole lot of cases. Well, unless we count some semantic difference there, but the actual numbers are the same. Of course this doesn't apply if your use-case regularly gzips > 4 GB files. Even in the cases where the number ends up being different, taking the modulo counts as pretending in my view, exactly because in many cases the result is the same.

Comment: @UncleBilly now we’re getting somewhere, thanks. Note that `tar` (at least, the version I’m using) *does* use `gzip`, it doesn’t use zlib. I’ll rework my answer to better address the OP’s concerns.

Comment: @eckes the CRC and size are stored in a footer, not a header, exactly so that they can be correctly determined and generated even when streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Besides limits of filesystems and storage systems and encryption containers, it might also be better to have smaller chunks for file transfers — especially if you use tools which do not support parallel upload, and restart of aborted transfers.

With smaller chunks you can work around all that, so I typically aim for 2 GB chunks everywhere. A checksum error is better to handle if you need to process 1 x 2 GB chunk again instead of a 100 GB file. Tar can normally split into multiple “tapes”.

If you can control your whole chain including USB sticks, storage accounts and transmission software, you don’t need to care (but especially for frictionless restores in panic moments having more flexibility is a plus anyway).